# Why My Update Query not working

Tags: c#, ado.net

When i click the update button, it's showing success, but my database is not updated.
What is wrong with my code:

```
private void CmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source......");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("update Leaves_Type set Leaves='"+txtltype.Text+"' where Leaves='"+txtltype.Text+"'");        
    comm.Connection = conn;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated");
    conn.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this exact query to see if it working without using c# ?

Comment: The fact you are not using query parameters and have database logic in a form method, which reads the controls directly, is making me pull my hair off.

Comment: @Euphoric. see i have also tries this -  SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("update Leaves_Type set Leaves=@Leaves"); 
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leaves",txtltype.Text); but it showing Error-Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Leaves_Type'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Leaves_Type'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

```
update Leaves_Type set Leaves='"+txtltype.Text+"' where Leaves='"+txtltype.Text+"'"
```

What you want to see updated? You update the field by same value.

Comment: i debugged my code . it showing txtltype= my updated value . yes i want to update same value

Comment: What you mean by update same value? Suppose `Leaves = 'A'` and you set it to `A`. What is the meaning?

Comment: see one textbox and one command button in form. Here i adding Leave_Type(EL/CL). suppose wrongly i have added ELE instead of El.now i want to edit this . how can i do this .

Answer (score 0):

I think In your case, Regarding the error, that you do a violation of the `PRIMARY KEY constraint`. You can maybe try first to update by using the `Primary Key`. And Also Use parametrized SQL.

Instead of this:

```
update Leaves_Type set Leaves='"+txtltype.Text+"' where Leaves='"+txtltype.Text+"'"
```

You can do like this:

```
update Leaves_Type set Leaves='"+txtltype.Text+"' where LeavesID= someValue " //And you can retrieve
                 //   someValue by appropriate Request if LeavesID is your PrimaryKey
```

Comment: have i take one more textbox for leaveid.

Comment: Read my comment after. Because you are trying to update a value by a the same value.